# Insert/Delete into MySQL/MariaDB, automatically show in React table

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

When the user clicks on a button in a `node.js/express/react/socket.io` application, I want to gather the data and insert it into a MySQL/MariaDB table. Here is the question,

**Is there some sort of `React` control that will automatically update itself (display the rows in the DB table in a browser table) on those inserts (regardless of where the inserts and deletes are coming from)? I also want the `React` control to update itself on deletes from the DB table that it is "linked" or "listening" to.** Similar to the way in `.Net`, you can attach a `Dataset` to a `SQL` query and further attach that to a GUI `GridView control`.

I understand that `React` runs on the client, but it does communicate with `Node` which is server side. So there has to be some protocol dance(google protocol buffers?) that goes back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to query the DB after an insert or delete and emit messages containing the data as a callback to the query.

Something like this pseudo-JS:

```
connection.query('delete query here', () => {
  connection.query('search query here', (data) => {
    io.emit('asdf', data);
  });
});
```

Comment: What is the glue between what your example appears to be server code (Node.js) and the GUI in React.js? I know I can build the whole [middleware] stack myself, I am hoping for a more shrinked wrapped solution.

Comment: Actually, you are saying use socket.io for the glue. That might be simple enough with say JSON or XML as the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much an answer as it is research. I noticed this article

https://www.sitepoint.com/using-node-mysql-javascript-client/

And also it appears that is useful to use an ORM like `Firenze`